# preg_split() 2 letters and decimal

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I have a string and this string should be an array.

But the first 2 letters are variable and I need the 5 next digits (whether empty or not). The last 5 digits are numeric with a decimal point or empty ( `$string="AB3 .  ";`)

An example:

```
$string = "AB10.00";

$arr[0] = "AB";
$arr[1] = "10.00";
```

I would like to use `preg_split()` for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean `substr()` ?

```
$string = "AB10.00";
$arr[0] = substr($string, 0, 2); // $arr[0] == 'AB'
$arr[1] = substr($string, 2); // $arr[1] == '10.00'
```

Comment: `$arr[1] = substr($string, 2, 6);` since OP is after last 5 digits (5+1 for the decimal point). Or does it need to work out whether there is a decimal point?

Comment: I didn't specify the length for the second substr because I couldn't figure if the point was part of the 5 digits or not.

Comment: yes thanks, substr() sorry but, i don't see the forest for the trees.